# how do i reset my htc desire 510 when factory/hard reset buttons wont work and i dont have my password?

Tags: factory-reset, htc-desire

I have tried holding volume down and power multiple times, i can't access the boot menu.  I tried accessing it every way possible with no success. I cant get into the phone to reset because I don't remember the password. How can i reset the phone or get into it somehow?

Comment: Have you tried the [advice from HTC's pages](http://www.htc.com/us/support/htc-desire-510-cricket/howto/550842.html)? They e.g. mention you should first remove the battery for a few seconds, re-insert it, pressing vol-down, and only then press and hold the power button – and keep both buttons pressed until "the screen with the three Android images" appears.

Answer (score 1):

When your phone starts and you connect it to your PC you can restart your phone into bootloader using adb (USB-Debugging has to be enabled).

1. Connect device to PC and be sure that the drivers are installed
2. Download the Android-SDK (it includes adb) or find a stand alone on google
3. navigate to this folder and run `adb devices`
4. when your Device is shown your drivers are correctly installed, if not check this
5. Now run `adb reboot-bootloader` and you are done

If USB-Debugging is disabled you have to try it with the hardware buttons. Remember that you have to press (and hold) the volume-down-button first and then press (and hold) the power-button until the Android images appear. You can also try to remove the battery for a few minutes and try again, sometimes this helps